# Problema al insertar datos en MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tengo un formulario HTML, y el problema es que cuando lleno los campos, y envío, la tabla no tira ningún registro después de que examino. El código corre sin errores, pero como digo, no llega ningún dato a la misma tabla. No comprendo que pueda estar pasando. Les agradecería que me sacaran la duda.

Mi formulario:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Formulario</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<form action="insertar.php" method="POST">
    <Label for="nombre">Nombre:</Label>
    <input type="text" name="nombre" required=""placeholder="Escribe tu nombre..."/><br><br>
    <label for="cuidad">Cuidad:</label>
    <input type="text" name="cuidad"  required=""placeholder="Escribe tu cuidad..."/> <br><br>
    <label for="comida favorita">Comida favorita:</label>
    <input type="text" name="comida favorita" required="" placeholder="Escribe tu comida favorita..."/><br><br>
    <label for="estado civil">Estado civil:</label>
   <input type="text" name="estado civil" required="" placeholder="Escribe tu estado civil..."/><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Mi conexión PHP:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(0);
$PDO = new 
PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_comentarios;charset=UTF8','root','' );
try { 
      echo "datos enviados correctamente";
     $sql=$PDO->prepare("INSERT INTO prueba2(nombre, cuidad, comida 
     favorita, 
     estado civil) VALUES (:nombre, :cuidad, :comida favorita, :estado 
     civil)");
      $sql->bindParam(':nombre',$_POST['nombre']);
      $sql->bindParam(':cuidad',$_POST['cuidad']);
      $sql->bindParam(':comida favorita', $_POST['comida favorita']);
      $sql->bindParam(':estado civil',$_POST['estado civil']);
      $sql->execute();

     }catch(PDOException $e) {
                        echo "Fallo de conexion al enviar los datos:".$e ->getMessage();
     }

     ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema son los espacios en los nombres de los campos y de las variables.
A los campos encerralos entre `, y para las variables utilizá guiones bajos.
Probá así:

```
<?php 
        error_reporting(0);
        $PDO = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_comentarios;charset=UTF8','root','' );
        try { 
            echo "datos enviados correctamente";
            $sql=$PDO->prepare("INSERT INTO prueba2(nombre, cuidad, `comida favorita`, `estado civil`) VALUES (:nombre, :cuidad, :comida_favorita, :estado_civil)");
            if (!$sql) {
                echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
                print_r($PDO->errorInfo());
            }
            else
            {
                $sql->bindParam(':nombre',$_POST['nombre']);
                $sql->bindParam(':cuidad',$_POST['cuidad']);
                $sql->bindParam(':comida_favorita', $_POST['comida favorita']);
                $sql->bindParam(':estado_civil',$_POST['estado civil']);
                $sql->execute();
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
                   echo "Fallo de conexion al enviar los datos:".$e ->getMessage();
        }  
?>
```

Suerte!

Comment: Sigue sin mostrarme nada.

Comment: Para ver los errores cambiale el "error_reporting(0);" por "error_reporting(E_ALL);" y comentame qué error te da.

Comment: No muestra ningún error. Sigue siendo todo igual.

Comment: ¿Tampoco graba nada en la base de datos?

Comment: Absolutamente nada. El orden de la tabla es Id, nombre, cuidad, comida favorita, estado civil, y nada. Aun agregando el id al código, sigue siendo lo mismo.

Comment: Modifiqué el código para que muestre si hay un error en el prepare.  ¿Lo podrás probar?

Comment: No, no hay ningún error. Me fui a fijar a la base de datos; actualice, y sigue siendo lo mismo. Que extraño.

Answer (score 0):

estaba viendo tu codigo y en la parte HTML debes asignarle un NAME y placeholder a cada variable para luego usar bindparam().

Ejemplo:

```
// Set the variables for the person we want to add to the database
$first_Name = "Thom";
$last_Name = "Vial";
$email = "thom.v@some.com";
```

Para Luego usarlos con los placeholders de la siguiente manera:

```
// Here we create a variable that calls the prepare() method of the database object
// The SQL query you want to run is entered as the parameter, and placeholders are written like this :placeholder_name
$my_Insert_Statement = $my_Db_Connection->prepare("INSERT INTO Students (name, lastname, email) VALUES (:first_name, :last_name, :email)");
```

y al final usamos bindparam() de la siguiente manera :

```
// Now we tell the script which variable each placeholder actually refers to using the bindParam() method
// First parameter is the placeholder in the statement above - the second parameter is a variable that it should refer to
$my_Insert_Statement->bindParam(:first_name, $first_Name);
$my_Insert_Statement->bindParam(:last_name, $last_Name);
$my_Insert_Statement->bindParam(:email, $email);
```

Luego a metodo de seguridad ejecutamos la query pero agregamos una respuesta booleana en caso de que el resultado sea un error y no podamos registrar los datos en la base de datos:

```
// Execute the query using the data we just defined
// The execute() method returns TRUE if it is successful and FALSE if it is not, allowing you to write your own messages here
if ($my_Insert_Statement->execute()) {
  echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
  echo "Unable to create record";
}
```

Aclaremos para que sirve Bindparam():

> bindParam() – Este método evalúa los datos cuando se alcanza el método
>   execute(). La primera vez que el script llega a un método execute(),
>   ve que $first_Name corresponde a “Thom”, vincula ese valor y ejecuta
>   la consulta. Cuando el script llega al segundo método execute(), ve
>   que $first_Name ahora corresponde a “John”, vincula ese valor y
>   ejecuta nuevamente la consulta con los nuevos valores. Lo que es
>   importante recordar es que definimos la consulta una vez y la
>   reutilizamos con diferentes datos en diferentes puntos del script.

Comment: Me parece estas equivocado, PHP ocupa el atributo name para recuperar el valor, el ID es para JS

Comment: Toda la razón!, Mala mía lo editaré

Comment: Eso y además el placeholder es un valor opcional y no determinante en este caso

Comment: Estimado, es debido a los placeholder su error!